# Cakephp 4: FIND_IN_SET not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have an array, `$submenus`, in my app that I implode to a delimited string:

```
$subs = implode(',', $submenus);
```

The string will look something like this: `'ml_,nc_,msr_'`. These values are stored in a field called `group_prefix` in my `submenus` table. Each `submenu` row has a unique `group_prefix`.

The following code builds menus and submenus from a database:

```
    $menus = $this->Menus->find('all', [
        'order' => ['Menus.display_order ASC'],
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain' => [
            'Submenus' => [
                'conditions' => [
                    'Submenus.status' => 1,
                    'FIND_IN_SET("' . $subs . '", Submenus.group_prefix)'
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $this->set('menus', $menus);
```

It works fine until I add the `FIND_IN_SET` condition on `Submenus`. When I do, I get no submenus returned, just the main menus. Debug confirms that the string is formatted propery. Doesn't error out, I just get no resultset.

When I run the submenus query in MySQL, it works.

```
set @prefixes = 'ml_,nc_,msr_';
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `submenus` WHERE `status` = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(`submenus`.`group_prefix`, @prefixes);

+----+---------------------------+
| id | name                      |
+----+---------------------------+
|  4 | Mission Lessons Module    |
|  5 | MSR Module                |
|  8 | Work Authorization Module |
+----+---------------------------+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code has the list of submenus first, and the field second; the working query has them the other way around.

Comment: @GregSchmidt: Go figure. The one thing I didn't try. Oddly, it works this way in my Cake 2.x app just fine. Must be a 3.x/4.x quirk.

Comment: A little offtopic, but no matter where the `$subs` data stems from, even if it currently stems from a definitely secure source, _**never** directly include it in a raw SQL snippet_ if it can be avoided - that's how SQL injection vulnerabilities happen! [**Please use bindings!**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#binding-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to reverse the order of arguments in FIND_IN_SET.